# how to get fabricJS to work with touch events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build, fabricjs

I have an application developped with phonegap and I am testing the touch support for fabricJS but somehow it doesn't work for me.

I tried creating a custom version [here](http://fabricjs.com/build/) but it doesn't work with it.

I have [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orihadar/F6UU4/48/) where I used another version called fabric_events.js but it doesn't seems to work too. (BTW how do you upload your own version to jsfiddle?)

so I tried the FabricJS [touch events demo](http://fabricjs.com/touch-events/) and it DOES work!!

since the demo worked I tried to download it's own version from http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric_with_gestures.js but still no luck.

this is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, user-scalable=true" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fabric_with_gestures.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >


        $(document).ready

        (
            function () {

                var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');


                // Do some initializing stuff
                fabric.Object.prototype.set({
                    transparentCorners: false,
                    cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
                    cornerSize: 12,
                    padding: 5
                });

                alert('fabric.isTouchSupported=' + fabric.isTouchSupported);
                var info = document.getElementById('info');
                canvas.on({
                    'touch:gesture': function () {
                        var text = document.createTextNode(' Gesture ');
                        info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
                    },
                    'touch:drag': function () {
                        var text = document.createTextNode(' Dragging ');
                        info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
                    },
                    'touch:orientation': function () {
                        var text = document.createTextNode(' Orientation ');
                        info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
                    },
                    'touch:shake': function () {
                        var text = document.createTextNode(' Shaking ');
                        info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
                    },
                    'touch:longpress': function () {
                        var text = document.createTextNode(' Longpress ');
                        info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
                    }
                });


                fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function (img) {
                    img.scale(0.5).set({
                        left: 150,
                        top: 150,
                        angle: -15
                    });
                    canvas.add(img);
                });

                canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
                    left: 50,
                    top: 50,
                    fill: '#269926',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    originX: 'left',
                    originY: 'top',
                    hasControls: true,
                    hasBorders: true,
                    selectable: true
                }));

                var obj = new fabric.Rect({
                    left: 20,
                    top: 20,
                    fill: '#555555',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    originX: 'left',
                    originY: 'top',
                    hasControls: true,
                    hasBorders: true,
                    selectable: true
                });
                canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
                canvas.setActiveObject(obj)
                //canvas.sendToBack(obj)
            }

        );
    </script>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c" width="200" height="200" style='z-index:-1'></canvas>
    <p id='info' style='background: #eef; width: 583px; padding: 10px; overflow: scroll; height: 80px'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. I am working with Fabric.js at the moment and I do not have any problems with gestures. I have tried your code, it is generally working if you care for three things:

1.) Very important: Please remove `style='z-index:-1'` from the canvas itself. The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element and a negative number will not allow you to interact with the canvas in your example. More information: [CSS z-index Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).
2.) Are you sure that you had created a Custom Build with "Interaction" and "Gestures"? "Gestures" is dependent on "Interaction". If you are unsure, create a Custom Build with all modules except "Node" (unless you want to use Node.js later).
3.) Fabric.js and jQuery must be in the subfolder 'js' regarding to your code. But I would think that it was like that already.

Then it should work for you, too.